# predicted probability using logistic regression in R equals 1

Tags: r, probability, glm

I have a simple glm model looks as:

```
glm.fit=glm(Retention2~Email+Pay.method, data=train, family = binomial)
```

All DV and IVs are categorical variables with two levels.

The outcome of the `glm` is:

[image]

when I calculated the predicated probabilities, the probability value is 1.000 when Pay.Method is 0. The syntax and output is listed below:

```
glm.fit.prob=predict(glm.fit, newdata = test2, type="response")
```

[image]

It seems that whenever the `pay.method ="EZ PAY"`, the probability will be 0. I think mathematically the reason is that the `coeff` of Email is so much smaller than intercept and Pay.method. I wonder if my understanding is correct and if so, any insight of how to work around this?

Comment: thanks! it did give me a better fit although not as good as using LDA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is called clear separation case. Look into your data when you have `pay.method ="EZ PAY"` then either almost observation might be zero or almost all will be 1. So ideally you dont need a model to predict because you can say whether outcome will be 0 or 1 without model (now if its genuine case or because of lack of data is another question). Its better to remove those cases from training data and then train the model (in your case remove all observations with `pay.method ="EZ PAY"`).

Now why this behavior. Logistic regression maximum likelihood estimation is not very good to deal with the case of the clear separation; for good coverage refer Hastie Tibshirani's statistical learning book. They also recommend using using discriminant analysis as it is better for dealing with such cases.

Comment: Thanks for the input. i did try LDA, which does give much better predicted probabilities, and overall prediction accuracy (72%).  However, i feel there is a drawback of using LDA that i won't able to get the CI of the posterior probability as I would if using glm.   For glm, if i include type="link" and se=TRUE, then i can calculate the CI for predicted probability. Any way I can go around this? Thanks!

Comment: one more question, when you say dropping the cases where pay.method=EZ PAY, is that the same as only include EMAIL as the predictor. Because there are only two levels in pay.method, i do not see including this variable after dropping all the cases with one level?

Comment: If this is your "complete" data then yes. If no then look for more data. problem of clear separation becomes less likely when you have more data. Logically just because someone using EZEEPAY will not be causing any attrition is illogical. There will be definitely be someone like that. Its just that your data doesn't capture him/er.

Comment: I dont think there is some CI is LDA but 4.4.2 and 4.4.3 of ISLR book (http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf) can answer all your questions.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: Rather than dropping say it is an oracle which can predict outcome with 100% surety. Dropping variable may be an insult to oracle variable. (Not sure but If I have heard) this problem also comes if subset of data can be predicted perfectly based on value of some regressor. Academician may want to drop those variable but say for high freq trader single oracle variable will be search of lifetime.